# Formatting using innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

Just a small problem, basically, the font styles I have set for these specific IDs are not working, and are being shown in the browser as the preset font for the page, here's the CSS code:

```
#para
    {
    font: #F00;
    }
```

Here is the JavaScript code:

```
document.getElementById("para").innerHTML="As you can see, the answer is";
```

I have placed the id into a paragraph tag in my HTML file, but the font styling isn't working

Answer (score 2):

To style the font color is to use the color property:

```
#para {
    color: #F00;
}
```

See this for more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/font

Comment: It happens, sometimes I feel like font-color would've been more intuitive.... there's already font-family, font-weight, font-style.